# unity object reset button and slider

Tags: user-interface, button, unity-game-engine, reset

I want to make that on keyboard r button press reset object into position: x112 y8 z153. Object name is Sphere i can rename it.

And i want a gui slider that can change forceadder 50f in game from 0 to 500.

I am a beginner. Just finished begginer tutorials. What code do i need to get? i tried to make that reset button my self but dosent do anything to me it says in debug that its pressed but it dosent reset it. Soo i removed that code.

My code right now:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ShootMeBall : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float forceadder = 500f;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        rigidbody.AddForce (transform.forward * forceadder);
        rigidbody.useGravity = true;
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log ("I am awake.");
        Screen.lockCursor = true;
        gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.yellow;
    }
}
```

Comment: See my edit on the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution(You will need to drag the object you're moving into the scripts GameObject variable in the inspector, and the slider into the slider slot):

```
   using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class Example : MonoBehavior
{

    public GameObject go;
    public Slider slider;

    private float force;

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            go.transform.position = new Vector3(112f, 8f, 153f);
        }

        force = (float)slider.value;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set the min/max values of the slider, and the value "Use whole numbers" to true if it matters.